# Automate a Gate Valve

Tags: plant-care

I am looking for a way to attach a 12v Servo, Solonoid, linear actuator, etc... to a 1.5" gate valve, in order to control the valve electronically.

Here is the gate valve i will be using:
[image]

The valve is fairly easy to push/pull open/close.

I was thinking of attaching a nema 14 stepper motor, with a lead screw through the handle of the valve. (in a threaded nut) to act as a linear actuator.

I also thought of grabbing a pre-built linear actuator, however these can get expensive. The gate valve is $4, and i would like to cost of the build to remain < $10-$15, as i will be needing multiple.

Any ideas will be extremely beneficial.

Comment: This may be a better fit for the Home Improvement / DIY stack site; https://diy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: But personally, I would just try to track down a solenoid valve that fit my needs and budget.

Comment: I used one of these for a while. Very surprising how stiff it became to close after a few seasons outdoors

Comment: I do not think you can go with such low budget. You have a 1"5 pipe so possibly a high flow. And you want to use a plastic gate (and the core is made by 4 pieces keep by screw. Go with standard solenoids, so less problem with peak current (and it is standard for such works, so you find many blue-print controllers online + software). Check Adafruits and check if you can use a lower diameter just for the valve.